# Can't install a script, script errors

Tags: php, mysql

I have some problems with a script I found here: http://www.phpkode.com/source/s/proxier/proxier/Proxier.class.php
Can't make it work, I created the database, the cron file but I still receive few errors after running the cron:

```
Warning: mysql_fetch_row(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in /home/.../Proxier.class.php on line 265

Warning: mysql_fetch_row(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in /home/.../Proxier.class.php on line 352
```

I need some help to understand how to make the script work properly.

Answer (score 1):

The docs for mysql_query says:

"For SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE, EXPLAIN and other statements returning resultset, mysql_query() returns a resource on success, or FALSE on error."

Your error says that the argument is not a resource, which tells me it is returning FALSE due to some error.  My guess is the table doesn't exist or there is some typo in the query.  Without more information on the database we can't help much more than that.

The docs also say:

"mysql_query() will also fail and return FALSE if the user does not have permission to access the table(s) referenced by the query."

So depending on what user is running the process you may not have permission to access the table.

Answer (score 0):

Display the error by doing so:

```
// The link you provided: Line - 264
// Modify it to this:
$res = mysql_query("select ...") or die("Error: ". mysql_error());
```

this way you will know what went wrong. In my opinion the query simply failed because your table does not have the same fields. But let the error tell you that.

Comment: It's true, Error: Table 'bynso_proxyservers.proxies' doesn't exist, this is the original sql files, there is no table called "proxies", http://www.phpkode.com/source/s/proxier/proxier/mysql.sql

Comment: good, now you create the table and your problem is solved

Comment: Yes, now the script is working. Thank you

Comment: if it helped you, can vote my answer up

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the configurations is not correct, make sure to pass the database name, user, password and table.

The error you are gettings is because mysql_query is failing, either because the connection failed or the table doens't exist or match what's expected from it (that is columns ip, time_added, active).